# Disallow new tabs in Chrome window (open new tabs in other window instead)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

When using native or web apps in Chrome it is quite distracting when new tabs are opened in the same window. Is there a way to disallow new tabs in a specific window, and force all new tabs to be opened in a specific window? To be clear, opening all tabs in new windows, which some extensions do, is not a good solution.

Ideal scenario:
1. Open web app in new Chrome window
2. Turn on "block new tabs in this window"
3. When clicking ctrl+T a tab opens in another Chrome window if possible, or a new window if only the "blocker" window is already open.

If there are other browsers who supports this feature, please let me know.

**UPDATE**:
I forgot to mention I am using a Mac. Due to this the accepted solution did not solve my issue all the way, but it got me looking in the right direction. The solution is to use a service called Applicationize as described in  https://eladnava.com/create-application-shortcuts-on-mac-with-applicationize/

Comment: Is this possible with the browser window (not the PWA)? I want to have a few sets of tabs in one of my browser windows and lock that window so that it always has only those sets of tabs in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create application shortcuts that provide a similar behavior:

1. Open your web app.
2. On the main Chrome menu click `More Tools` and then `Add to Desktop`.
3. Check the `Open as window' checkbox.

You'll get a shortcut on your desktop that will open in its own window. If you click or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click links in this window, they will open as tabs in another Chrome window, or in an existing one if there is already a window open.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am mainly using Chrome on a Mac, and the "Add to Desktop" option is not available there. However, you did bring me in the right direction, and the recipe at https://eladnava.com/create-application-shortcuts-on-mac-with-applicationize/ pretty much does what you describe. I will accept this answer.

Comment: The "Add to Desktop" option is not there on Windows either. There is an option called "Create shortcut..." which seems to be what's described (if you also check the "Open as window" checkbox). This moves the tab to its own window. Visited links won't show up as tabs in this window, but you also can't manually drag tabs into this window, or create the window with multiple tabs to begin with (which I find limiting). Personally, I'd like an "open link in new tab, different window" option (i.e. if I'm opening the link from a Chrome window, it can open in an existing window, just not this one).