# How can I lock a Google Chrome window so no new tabs open on that window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, office365, web-application

I am using office 365 for email and calendaring.  When I open a link in my email tab, I want it to always open in another window.  But I don't want this to happen on just any website.

Is there a way to lock a tab to a chrome window so it's the only tab on that window?  IE, to make a tab behave as if it were an app?

Maybe I just need to know the right terminology for this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this Q&A solves it, but I am creating this question/answer for searchability.

https://superuser.com/a/1139556/10429